# Docker image for multi-maven modules (Hexagonal Architecture)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to create a docker image with a dockerfile with multiple maven modules and I faced alot of erros.
Here is my architecture

```
+ -- MyMainProject
     + -- application           <- Module 1
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- domain                <- Module 2
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- bootloader            <- Module 3
     |     `src/main/java/BootloaderApplicationLuncher (Java application launcher)
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- infrastructure        <- Module 4 (has 3 modules)
          + -- infrastructure 1          <- Module 4.1
          |     `  --  pom.xml
          + -- infrastructure 2          <- Module 4.2
          |     `  --  pom.xml
          + -- infrastructure 3          <- Module 4.3
          |     `  --  pom.xml
     | -- pom.xml
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6-alpine as build

WORKDIR /home/app
COPY application/pom.xml application/pom.xml
COPY domain/pom.xml domain/pom.xml
COPY bootloader/pom.xml bootloader/pom.xml
COPY infrastructure/pom.xml infrastructure/pom.xml
COPY infrastructure/adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa/pom.xml infrastructure/adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa/pom.xml
COPY infrastructure/adapter-persistence-spring-data-mongodb/pom.xml infrastructure/adapter-persistence-spring-data-mongodb/pom.xml
COPY infrastructure/adapter-rest/pom.xml infrastructure/adapter-rest/pom.xml
COPY pom.xml .

RUN mvn -B -e -C org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM maven:3.6-alpine as BUILDER
COPY --from=build /root/.m2 /root/.m2
COPY --from=build /home/app /home/app
COPY application/src /home/app/application/src
COPY domain/src /home/app/domain/src
COPY bootloader/src /home/app/bootloader/src
COPY infrastructure/src /home/app/infrastructure/src
COPY infrastructure/adapter-rest/src /home/app/infrastructure/adapter-rest/src
COPY infrastructure/adapter-persistence-spring-data-mongodb/src /home/app/infrastructure/adapter-persistence-spring-data-mongodb/src
COPY infrastructure/adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa/src /home/app/infrastructure/adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa/src
#RUN mvn -B -e clean install -DskipTests=true


FROM openjdk:8-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY --from=builder /home/app/bootloader/target/bootloader-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar .
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/home/app/bootloader/bootloader-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Error:
**Failed to execute goal on project application: Could not resolve dependencies for project io.example:application:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact io.example:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release) -> [Help 1]**